# Validity checks for ReferenceClass

Tags: r

S4 classes allow you to define validity checks using `validObject()` or `setValidity()`. However, this does not appear to work for ReferenceClasses.

I have tried adding `assert_that()` or `if (badness) stop(message)` clauses to the `$initialize()` method of a ReferenceClass. However, when I simulate loading the package (using `devtools::load_all()`), it must try to create some prototype class because the `initialize` method executes and fails (because no fields have been set).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Implement a validity method on the reference class

```
A = setRefClass("A", fields=list(x="numeric", y="numeric"))

setValidity("A", function(object) {
    if (length(object$x) != length(object$y)) {
        "x, y lengths differ" 
    } else NULL
})
```

and invoke the validity method explicitly

```
> validObject(A())
[1] TRUE
> validObject(A(x=1:5, y=5:1))
[1] TRUE
> validObject(A(x=1:5, y=5:4))
Error in validObject(A(x = 1:5, y = 5:4)) : 
  invalid class "A" object: x, y lengths differ
```

Unfortunately, `setValidity()` would need to be called explicitly as the penultimate line of an initialize method or constructor.

Comment: I like this approach as it moves the ugly validity checking code out of the initialize method. Although I'm not sure whether this has any additional advantages to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you can do this in `initialize`. It should have the form:

```
initialize = function (...) {
  if (nargs()) return ()
  # Capture arguments in list
  args <- list(...)
  # If the field name is passed to the initialize function
  # then check whether it is valid and assign it. Otherwise
  # assign a zero length value (character if field_name has 
  # that type) 
  if (!is.null(args$field_name)) { 
    assert_that(check_field_name(args$field_name))
    field_name <<- field_name  
  } else {
    field_name <<- character()
  }
  # Make sure you callSuper as this will then assign other 
  # fields included in ... that weren't already specially 
  # processed like `field_name`
  callSuper(...)
}
```

This is based on [the strategy](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/R/AllClass.R) set out in the lme4 package.